# How to use the result from a second select in my first select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use a second `SELECT` to get some ID, then use that ID in a second `SELECT` and I have no idea how.

```
SELECT Employee.Name 
FROM Emplyee, Employment 
WHERE x = Employment.DistributionID 
(SELECT Distribution.DistributionID FROM Distribution 
       WHERE Distribution.Location = 'California') AS x
```

**This post got long, but here is a short "tip"**

While the syntax of my select is bad, the logic is not. I need that "x" somehow. Thus the second `select` is the most important. Then I have to use that "x" within the first `select`. I just don't know how

**/Tip**

This is the only thing I could imagine, I'm very new at Sql, I think I need a book before practicing, but now that I've started I'd like to finish my small program.

**EDIT:**

Ok I looked up joins, still don't get it

```
SELECT Employee.Name 
    FROM Emplyee, Employment 
    WHERE x = Employment.DistributionID 
    LEFT JOIN Distribution ON
    (SELECT Distribution.DistributionID FROM Distribution 
           WHERE Distribution.Location = 'California') AS x
```

Get error msg at `AS` and `Left`

I use name to find ID from upper red, I use the ID I find FROM upper red in lower table. Then I match the ID I find with Green. I use Green ID to find corresponding Name

[image]

I have `California` as output data from C#. I want to use `California` to find the DistributionID. I use the DistributionID to find the EmployeeID. I use EmployeeID to find Name

**My logic:**

```
Parameter: Distribution.Name (from C#)

Find DistributionID that has Distribution.Name
Look in Employment WHERE given DistributionID 
      reveals Employees that I am looking for (BY ID)
Use that ID to find Name
      return Name
```

Tables:

**NOTE:** In this example picture the Employee repeats because of the select, they are in fact singular

In "Locatie" (middle table) is Location, I get location (again) from C#, I use `California` as an example. I need to find the `ID` first and foremost!

[image]

Sory they are not in english, but here are the create tables:

[image]

Comment: Typically the way you get related records based on a common ID is using a "join". You might read up on joins for a bit.

Comment: But, do you need the results of the first `SELECT`, or is your desired output only the results from the second `SELECT`?

Comment: Perhaps a bit early to introduce subqueries.

Comment: @Lamak I use this with a C# program, so the first select needs data from C# (in this case 'California')

Comment: How is the `Employment` table related to the `Employee` table?

Comment: @showdev Emplyment has a list of Employees that are situated in Distribution (as in where they live). Emplyment was just the word I translated to english on the spot, maybe it's not perfect

Comment: For one, you are mis-spelling Employee/Emplyee in either the first or second line.  See either of the answers below on how to use joins.  You shouldn't be slecting an entire table and saving that result as x and then filtering where x equals something

Comment: @Kalec - Do you really expect us to understand your problem fully if you not posting tables and some fake or real data? How hard is this to understand and how hard is to create structures to get better answers?

Comment: @KyleMit I tried to add some logic, I'll add the tables

Comment: Wow, you also need to read up on [Normalization Practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  Beyond that... can you show us the results you expect, given the sample data you're showing?  Complete with source table and column names?  And where are you expecting to find `California`, anyways?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Actually I'm in 3NF. I won't go beyond that no matter what. All non key elements refer the key, only the key and nothing but the key, as it were. The first table (in the second picture) is just a select of multiple tables. Actually Employee has an ID, everything else is a reference towards that ID. I won't go into any other details, but again ... I am in the third normal form. Also I can't explain this any better than I already have. I have a `Distribution` with `ID` and `Name`. I use `Name` to find `ID`(I think I've said this at least 5 times in the question)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse *I'll use zone and worker to maybe lessen the confusion.*  And after I have `Zone.ID` (again obtained from Zone.Name) I want to know what does that mean. Who works in zone identified by `Zone.ID` ? I get `Worker ID` (or emplyee id from the table that makes that connection, namely Employment) ... I use that to find the name `Worker Name` (or again employee name)

Comment: Table `Distribution` is not completely normalized - ignoring the surrogate (auto-gen) id of the table, individual table rows should _usually_ be unique.  Can you give the example output of the query?  Try to pare your question down to solely the following: Your table definitions and sample data, desired output, and current effort.  Lengthy explanations don't always clarify the issue.  Oh, and either completely translate your table/column names, or stop referring to them in their translated forms, it confuses things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT angajati.Nume 
FROM angajati 
JOIN angajari  ON angajati.AngajatID = angajari.AngajatID
JOIN distribuire ON angajari.distribuireid = distribuire.distribuireid
WHERE distribuire.locatie = 'california'
```

As you have a table mapping employees to their distribution locations, you just need to join that one in the middle to create the mapping.  You can use variables if you like for the WHERE clause so that you can call this as a stored procedure or whatever you need from the output of your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are connecting Emplyee(sic?) and Employment, but you want to use a join to connect two tables and in the join specify how the tables are related.  Joins usually look best when they have aliases so you don't have to repeat the entire table name.  The following query will get you all the information from both Employment and Distribution tables where the distribution location is equal to california.  You can join employee to employment to get name as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employment e
JOIN Distribution d on d.DistributionID = e.DistributionID
WHERE d.Location = 'California'
```

This will return the contents of both tables.  To select particular records use the alias.[Col_Name] separated by a comma in the select statement, like d.DistributionID to return the DistributionID from the Distribution Table

Comment: I have the location (`California`) from C#, I need to use it to find DistributionID for California, with that ID I look into the Employment table and find the Employees in California. This query gives me an empty table

Comment: I added as much info as I could. Your select won't work because of what I've already said. I added a "tip" in my post, hope it helps.