# How to properly join these selects?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
[1] SELECT X.id FROM somwhere WHERE X.location = _stringReturnedFromC#_
            // I need ID from this table, I only know strin: Location (from C#)

[2] SELECT Y.NameID FROM _relationBetweenXandY_ xy WHERE xy.ID = [1]
           // I use the ID I just found in [1]

[3] SELECT Z.Name FROM Z WHERE Z.NameID = [2]
           // I use the ID I found in [2]
```

Now how can I tell `select [2]` that I am looking for `xy.ID = result from select [1]`

And `select [3]` that I'm looking for the name of the guy with the ID `Z.NameID`

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761088/how-to-use-the-result-from-a-second-select-in-my-first-select) but as far as I'm concerned that question is beyond saving.

```
Z table: 
      Z.Name, Z.NameID
Y Table: 
      Y.PLACE, Y.PlaceID // fixed, Used to be PlaceID, is inface string: Place
X Table:
      X.Name, X.PlaceID
```

If they have the same name, they are foreign keys (NameID, PlaceID)

This is how the actual code looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Angajati a
JOIN Distribuire d ON d.Locatie = 'Oradea'
// now I need to get d.DistribuireID while I know d.Locatie (d.location). How ?
JOIN Angajari an ON d.DistribuireID = an.DistribuireID
```

Thus

```
SELECT *
FROM TableX X 
   JOIN TableY y on x.PlaceId = y.PlaceId
   JOIN TableZ z on y.NameId = z.NameId
```

Does not work because I don't know Y.PlaceID, I just know Y.Place

**LAST EDIT**

Sorry if this is getting too long. Here is how it should look like (what I mean by that, even if the syntax won't work, this is the logic) Now I just need the syntax for this!

```
SELECT d.DistribuireID FROM Distribuire d WHERE d.Locatie = 'Oradea'
JOIN Angajari an ON an.DistribuireID = d.DistribuireID /*Here I'd need an.AngajatID for the locationID I just selected*/
JOIN Angajati a ON a.AngajatID = an.AngajatID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need some INNER JOINs:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableX X 
   JOIN TableY y on x.PlaceId = y.PlaceId
   JOIN TableZ z on y.NameId = z.NameId
```

Hope this helps.

-EDIT -- Why won't this work?  Sorry if I'm not understanding your question...

```
SELECT d.DistribuireID 
FROM Distribuire d 
   JOIN Angajari an ON an.DistribuireID = d.DistribuireID
   JOIN Angajati a ON a.AngajatID = an.AngajatID
WHERE d.Locatie = 'Oradea'
```

Good luck.

Comment: I may have asked the question slightly wrong. I'll get back to you as soon as I figure out what's not right.

Comment: I've eddited a small erorr on my part. Your joins won't work now and I still don't know how to make get my end result.

Comment: @Kalec -- I'm not sure I completely understand what you're looking for, but I've posted an update.  Let me know.